# How to use a webcam for image classifier?

Tags: video, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've trained my CNN model using Tensorflow and I used it to test images successfully. Now I want to use my model as a real-time classifier so I need to feed it a frame by frame captured video. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To use the webcam you can use OpenCV :

  ```
  import cv2
  import numpy as np

  #capture via webcam 0
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

  while True:
      # true or false for ret if the capture is there or not
      ret, frame = cap.read()
  ```
- You have to save you model that you have trained using by creating a .ckpt file you can do this easily :

  ```
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  # create your model 

  with tf.Session() as sess:
      # perform you training here 

      saver.save(sess, './my_trained_model')   # Save your Model
  ```
- After Saving the model use OpenCV to detect frames from the cam and before detecting frames you have to load your `my_trained_model`

  ```
  import tensorflow as tf
  import cv2

  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      saver.restore(sess, './my_trained_model')  # Restore your model 
      detection_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
      input_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_tensor:0') # Get the input tensor 
      output_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('output_tensor:0')  # Get the output tensor 
      while True:
          # true or false for ret if the capture is there or not
          ret, frame = cap.read()  # read fram from the webcam
          feed = {input_tensor: frame}
          prediction = sess.run(tf.argmax(output_tensor, 1), feed_dict=feed)  # make prediction
  ```
- If you want to classify multiple things from the web cam then you might have to implement a sliding window and for every sliding window you will get a prediction but this won't be real time
- I have suggested the above solution for Image classification and not for object detection
- If you apply an object detection technique like YOLO, SSD, R-CNN it will do the classification for you and this will be in real-time
- In object detection you first detect object and then perform classification on detected objects

**======================= UPDATED ======================**

- You can use Tensorflow Object Detection Api : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
- This is a real time object detection api
- I have tested the api myself and results are amazing
- I would suggest you to use that instead of using you own model which is image classification
- Here is the tutorial link  to ipython notebook ===> https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: Is it possible to feet the frame every two seconds ? 
 Can I use an object detection technique with the model I've trained ?

Comment: @SalhiFedi ... Yes you can change the FPS (Framerate per second)... Yes you can use your model with object detection technique like R-CNN

Comment: @Jai Understand that you are working on AI, could you please check my question and please advise how can I improve the detection using YOLO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839115/yolo-object-identification-more-rapidly-and-consistently

Comment: There are a lot of difference between image classification and object detection.