# YOLO object identification more rapidly and consistently

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js, yolo

Using `YOLO` and `p5.js` I am trying to identify the objects using my webcam. Even though, I gave permission to access the webcam, following are the problems. Is there any way we can improve the object identification more rapidly and consistently?

1. Once identified the green rectangular is not sticking around consistently. I need to move slightly for object identification.
2. I have `test.mp4` video saved locally, how can we do the object identification on saved video.

Following is my code:

```
let video; //Variable for video stream
let yolo;  //Initializing model method with YOLO.
let status; //Status check to determine whether the model has been loaded
let objects = []; //List of objects returned from YOLO

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 600); 
    video = createCapture(VIDEO); //Capturing live video from webcam
    video.size(400, 500);

    // Creating a YOLO method using ml5
    yolo = ml5.YOLO(video, startDetecting);

    // Hide the original video
    video.hide();
    status = select('#status');
}

function draw() {
    image(video, 0, 0, width, height); // Displaying image on a canvas
    for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)  //Iterating through all objects
    {
        noStroke();
        fill(0, 255, 0); //Color of text
        text(objects[i].label, objects[i].x * width, objects[i].y * height - 5); //Displaying the label
        noFill();
        strokeWeight(4); 
        stroke(0, 255, 0); // Define rectangular outline here
        rect(objects[i].x * width, objects[i].y * height, objects[i].w * width, objects[i].h * height);
    }
}

function startDetecting() {
    status.html('Model loaded!'); //When the model is loaded
    detect(); //Calling detect method
}

function detect() {
    yolo.detect(function(err, results) {
        objects = results; //Storing results in object
        detect(); //Continuous detection
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A possible solution is not to use p5.js and instead use getUserMedia() method for camera access. In this way you can mirror the video stream to an image element and detect the image element.
2. For the saved video file you can use HTML Media Capture to accept a video file and put it into HTML: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Once you have done that, you can make a function that enables the detection when you press the play button. Something like this.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

video.addEventListener('play', function() { // block of code }, 16);
```